# Join Oracle and Sqlite tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlite

I have a local (read and write) sqlite database and a remote (read-only) oracle database. I use ODBC to access both DBs (I use an application to access the DBs by ODBC and query as such: EXECUTE-QUERY SQLITE "SELECT ..." or EXECUTE-QUERY ORACLE "SELECT ...") . I tried searching the net for a way to be able to perform one query joining tables from the 2 databases, but all I find is how to create a database link from oracle to other DBs but that doesn't help me because I have no write priviledges for the Orcale DB so creations of database links, databases, tables, views are not allowed in ORACLE, all I can do is query there. Is there an efficient way to do this with the restraints that I have?

Comment: What if I replace the SQLITE with a local free Oracle Database Express Edition 11g (as connecting to sqlite seems problematic with the restrictions)? Will that make things easier? What would be the procedure then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I installed Oracle express edition and created a database link to the other (read-only) oracle database. That worked great.

Answer (score 1):

How big are the tables in oracle? Given the limits of the access you have and the technology you are working with ( sqlite and oracle are worlds apart ), your best bet would probably be to export the tables from oracle into sqlite, then do your queries all within  that.

Comment: ok it's a possibility, however the size of the oracle tables on the server is huge, I don't think it's practical to transfer the data for all the tables on the server to my local PC (local DB).